# How to navigate file upload window without knowing the elements using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have been trying to access the elements (input ID, button ID etc.) of a File Upload dialogue window using Selenium in Python, with no success. The File Upload window seems to be a Windows dialogue window. Have already tried the different solutions posted on this portal but nothing is working. Please assist.[Attached is the screenshot of the File Upload window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YXAG.png)

Comment: This is Windows File Explorer. You can't automate this using selenium. I think you are automating file upload for an website it will be good if you post that respective file upload HTML DOM code instead of this

Answer (score 0):

A webdriver controls remote sessions on browsers. We cannot modify the windows system file dialog with a webdriver.

Thus, let me enlighten you with a possible solution (it may not be exactly what you want, in which case we will iterate on the solution):

To popup a file dialog to upload a file, you probably would've needed to click on the following html. In human readable terms, it's a file input field.

```
<input type="file">
```

But actually, there's no need to directly click on it. You can simply find the element, and send the path of the file to upload.

```
pathOfFile = "C:/Users/John/yourPotatoIsTwoPotatoes.png"
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='file']")
element.send_keys(pathOfFile)
```

I'm not sure if you'll like the idea of passing a path name to the file input, so tell me if I've answered your question enough!

Comment: Thank you Mohamed and hams222 for your responses. I reached the File Upload window by clicking on the Document to Attach button using the following code - DocumentToAttachButton = GOLDwindow.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@onclick, 'tryUploadClick')]")
DocumentToAttachButton.click()   However, I am not able to access any of the File Upload dialogue windows elements through Selenium in Python.

Comment: Yea unfortunately , if you really want to upload a file by selecting through a File Upload Dialog, then it's not possible with Selenium Webdriver. However, you can consider getting the path of the file through a [tkinter file dialog](https://gist.github.com/Yagisanatode/0d1baad4e3a871587ab1) and then sending the path to DocumentToAttachButton like how I did above?

Comment: I already did try to send the file path to "DocumentToAttachButton" with send_keys but it ain't working. Following is the underlying script of the "DocumentToAttachButton" - <img class="editMagnifier" src="pics/transparent.gif" id="button_browse" style="cursor:pointer; cursor:hand;" alt="File To Upload" title="File To Upload" onclick="tryUploadClick();">  After clicking on this button, the File Upload window opens up and this is where I am stuck. If not selenium, is there any other way (other than AutoIt) to navigate this File Upload window to select the file through Python script?